# In NativeScript how to access external storage path on IOS

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using NativeScript + Angular. I have checked the `knownFolders.documents().path` for the IOS application and it's available for the current application. This `Document` Folder is private for the application and not accessible from Users/External apps.

Using this `knownFolders.documents().path` user can not access the downloaded file so I want to download the file in the root folder or in the External Storage folder so that the user can access the file.

Is there any way to access the External Storage path for the IOS?